# Using Numpy from keyword.py

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to use NumPy in a Python script that uses `pandas` to process an Excel file. However, one of my constraints is that my file must be named `keyword.py`, which causes an import error. The import error is traced back to a line `from keyword import iskeyword as _iskeyword` in `C:\Python27\lib\collections.py`, which I assume causes an error because my own `keyword.py` is overriding the default `keyword` module. Is there any way to avoid this collision?

Comment: "my file must be named keyword.py" <- that seems like a very unusual constraint.  Could you edit your question to include why you think this constraint holds?

Comment: @DSM this is a challenge from TopCoder and one of the constraints is that the entry point should be named keyword.py

Comment: `keyword` is in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser this is the problem, is there any way to have a module with the same name as one from the standard library?

Comment: Also relevant: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: I would not be surprised if this is a question that @MartijnPieters has answered more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty, but a `keyword.py` of

```
if True:
     import imp, sys

     keyword_loc = imp.find_module("keyword", sys.path[1:])[1]
     imp.load_source("keyword", keyword_loc)

import collections
print(collections.Counter)
```

fails with an AttributeError if we replace `True` with `False`, but gives me

```
(2.7) dsm@notebook:~/coding/kw$ python keyword.py 
<class 'collections.Counter'>
```

as is.  This works by finding out where the original keyword library is and manually importing it.  After this, any following attempts to import `keyword` will see that it's already there.

Answer (score 1):

For working with a single script, you can remove the current directory from the import search path.  That might be sufficient for working on your TopCoder problem, but I wouldn't recommend it as a long-term solution.  (Long-term: don't use file names that mirror the standard library.)

If the following script is called `keyword.py`, it can be run and the import of `collections` will not trigger an error.

```
# keyword.py

# Remove the current directory from the import search path
# This is a hack, but it will be sufficient for working with a
# single script that doesn't import any other modules from the
# current directory.
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]

import collections
print(collections)
```

Comment: Yeah, if there's only one script to worry about this is much simpler.

Comment: Attempting to run this file in PyCharm still produces [this output](http://pastebin.com/Ew2PrrPM), which is an error. The Python file that I'm trying to use [looks like this](http://pastebin.com/UT0SH4d3)

Comment: I don't have PyCharm installed, and I'm not using Windows, so I won't be able to reproduce that error.  Try running it from a command prompt, with a command something like `C:\Python27\python.exe keyword.py`.